# Build a Carousel with HTML and CSS only

Tags: html, css

I would like to build a Responsive Carousel based on pure CSS and HTML. I am trying to model it [as per this template](https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/Moderna/), but do not want it to use any Javascript or JQuery.

Here is what I have so far:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/niftyhawk/pen/jOWVNrN)

I Would like to have the carousel rotate slides when clicked on Previous and Next Buttons and also auto-rotate the slides every 5 seconds.

```
<a class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bx bx-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>

  <a class="carousel-control-next" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bx bx-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
```

Comment: You can't have any interaction without javascript. Also, how would you handle if the user clicks on a button right when a slide is going to animate?

Comment: There seems to be some tricks: https://css-tricks.com/css-only-carousel/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use HTML and CSS for the carousel, you at least need a javascript for the button. But if you insist, you can try out [Boostrap Carousel](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_carousel.asp). Its pretty easy to use and you dont need any javascript.